# Replacing rotary dimmer switch 2wires in wall

Tags: electrical, wiring, dimmer-switch

We're replacing a rotary dimmer switch. The wall has 1 white, 1 black wire. Kit has 2 box with 2 black wires and one green wire.  Do we use all 3 wires to connect with the 2 wires? How?

Answer (score 2):

If the kit has only two black wires and one green(ground) wire, then one black is connected to the black, the other black is connected to the white(nice time to put black tape on it) and the green is connected to the box and the bare wire from the old cable.

Connect with wire nuts or wagos.

Comment: I'd have stuck with your previous version, it was more complete.

Comment: @FreeMan  I reread the question and noticed the new switch did not have a white wire for neutral that I thought at first, it was just a simple switch.

Answer (score 2):

If the dimmer has marking for Line and load, then use that.

If not, connect one black to black and the other black to the white.